# How to create standalone executable file from python 3.5 scripts?

Tags: python, exe, python-3.5

Most of the programs available only support upto python version 3.4.

Answer (score 27):

You can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) which support python 3.5.

To install it with pip execute in terminal:
`pip install pyinstaller`

To make the .exe file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```