# py2exe SytaxError: invalid syntax (asyncsupport.py, line22)

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am using py2exe for the first time, and I have a Python program that works as intended when I run it.  When trying to compile the .exe file, I get the following error in the command prompt:

> error: compiling
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py' failed 
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax (asyncsupport.py, line 22)

The code I am using in my setup file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['csvParseOnBase.py'])
```

I also have the setup file and the csvParseOnBase.py file saved in the same location (D: drive).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in asyncsupport.py, line 22?

Comment: I added an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42215102/3154314